# css columns and content

Tags: html, css

This probably is the most frequently asked question however I am not really able to find anything that seems to work for me - I am a newbie @ styling/css.

I would like a cross browser compliant solution (IE9 or higher btw) where I can have as a header (first row) 3 columns:

```
Name_____DOB______Contact
```

underneath, there will be content. a row of data and I want the row of data (which is contained in a div) to be aligned correctly with the column headings.

Currently I have this:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
   <div style="width: 300px; float:left">Name</div>
   <div style="width: 200px; float:left">DOB</div>
   <div style="width: 100px; float:left">Contact</div>
</div>
```

in terms of the data, I am using MVC4 with Razor so I am just using a for loop to go through a collection of data and spitting it out in a div i.e:

```
[for loop here]

   <div id="refitem_@counter">
      [data here]
   </div>
[end for loop]
```

Comment: If you're creating a table use `<table>`

Comment: although using `<table>` is bad practice for creating layout. its the best practice for creating tables. so don't try to invent the wheel, for a table **use a `<table>`**.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using table because its old/outdated etc... and want to move forward with CSS3 and HTML5

Comment: Tables are only old and outdated for page layout. Tables serve a very useful purpose for displaying repeating data in rows and columns. I don't see tables ever disappearing from html.

Comment: Well, can anyone give a solution using the div's?

Comment: have you try diplay: table; display:table-row; and display:table-cell; I think this could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue with the same approach.

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 100%">
       <div style="width: 300px; float:left">Name</div>
       <div style="width: 200px; float:left">DOB</div>
       <div style="width: 100px; float:left">Contact</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%">
       <div style="width: 300px; float:left">Name 1</div>
       <div style="width: 200px; float:left">DOB 1</div>
       <div style="width: 100px; float:left">Contact 1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%">
       <div style="width: 300px; float:left">Name 2</div>
       <div style="width: 200px; float:left">DOB 2</div>
       <div style="width: 100px; float:left">Contact 2</div>
    </div>
    ..
</div>
```

I'm strongly dis-advise you to use that. use a table instead.
also (as a BTY): don't mix your markup and CSS, use something like that.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div>
       <div class="column col1">Name</div>
       <div class="column col2">DOB</div>
       <div class="column col3">Contact</div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div class="column col1">Name 1</div>
       <div class="column col2">DOB 1</div>
       <div class="column col3">Contact 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <div class="column col1">Name 2</div>
       <div class="column col2">DOB 2</div>
       <div class="column col3">Contact 2</div>
    </div>
    ..
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.column
{
    float: left;
}
.col1
{
    width: 300px;
}
.col2
{
    width: 200px;
}
.col3
{
    width: 100px;
}
```

`width: 100%;` is the default behaviour for a block element (like a div) so you should omit it.